# WiX MSI unexpectedly installed on-demand. Why?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX bootstrapper that installs 3 MSI files. The package is installed **per machine** (InstallScope="perMachine"). Users run bootstrapper.exe and everything works fine, but now I was tasked to create a separate MSI that would run the same bootstrapper.exe in silent mode. I did it via custom action, (I just run the bootstrapper.exe with the quiet parameter), but here's the thing: when I run this new MSI file, I see that it **runs under the NT AUTHORITY  / SYSTEM account**( contrary to the bootstrapper.exe, which runs under the current user account) and ***I think*** **this is the reason for my problem**.

The problem is that when I run the new MSI, the package is **installed in the advertise / on-demand mode**. I see the shortcut, I see the program in add/remove, but when I click on the program shortcut, the installer kicks in and finishes the installations. I can't afford that to happen, because the end user will not have the admin rights and this MSI is planned to be installed via GPO. So it must install completely.

I **compared MSI logs** of when the package is installed the old way (via bootsrapper.exe) and the new way (via the MSI wrapper) but **didn't see any significant differences**. The only significant difference that I can see so far is the fact that bootsrapper.exe runs in the user context and the new MSI (and subsequetly the bootsrapper.exe executed by it) run in the NT AUTHORITY / SYSTEM.

Am I on the right track with this or am I totally off? Thank you.

Comment: Multilevel chaining is not a good deployment engineering architecture. If your company's IT department's only tool is a hammer... and requires repackaging, they could simply extract the MSIs and reimplement your bootstrapper logic in their deployment tool.

Comment: Take a look at how the GPO deployment is done. IIRC a publish of an MSI  to the machine results in an on-demand install. If so, it needs to be assigned instead.

Comment: The bootstrapper is intended to run other MSI files in sequence - one after the other, it is not intended to be embedded in another MSI file and run via a custom action. In fact, **this is the opposite of what it is for** - it is specifically provided as a means to **not** have to kick off other installs from within MSI files, but rather to have things run in a proper sequence. **Push back these requirements to your management - they don't seem to make any sense**.